# Problem Applying a formula to a column in via additional column settings

Tags: 2007, date-time, calculated-column-formula

SharePoint Version is SharePoint 2007 standard

Scenario: I'm trying to apply a forumla from within the additional colum settings of a date/field data type.  In particular, one that'll return the text display of the day that a date falls on.  The formula I'd use in a calculated column is

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([DateFieldColumn]), "dddd")
```

However, I return the following error message.  Any other tweak returns unsupported syntax.

> "The formula contains a circular reference (the calculated column
>   refers to itself).  You must remove or change the circular reference."

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "Tuesday" from a Date try:

```
=TEXT([DateFieldColumn],"dddd")
```

If you want "2" from a date (that falls on a Tuesday) try:

```
=WEEKDAY([DateFieldColumn])
```

FWIW: "Pentalogic" provides a "cheat sheet" that will tell you all of this.